# How to restart VM in Azure ML Notebook?

Tags: cortana-intelligence, azure-machine-learning-service

I am writing code in Jupyter Notebook in Azure ML Studio.

At current moment every command causes kernel death. Even in new clear notebook I could not execute even `print 'hello'` - kernel died immediately.

Also I could not use bash commands like `!ls` - It crashes kernel too.

How could I restart my VM or restart session in Azure ML Studio with killing all running VM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found that if I go from notebook menu to File->Open, then I see all my notebooks, their statuses and I could shutdown them.

Also I have found that some of my closed notebooks were still alive and have shut them down.

After this my working notebook came back to life.

Answer (score 0):

First, sorry about the issues, this should be filed as a bug! We are still smoothing a few issues but wanted to share the notebook service which is why we have launched it under preview.

But, you can not reset a Notebook server. If you leave for about an hour, you should be assigned to a new VM when you log in, and I would expect to see this solved.